# Job getting account disabled Error, but works as normal when executed manually

Tags: sql-server, authorization, jobs

The account used in a linked external SQL Server was disabled, by the external server, temporaly. After the restoration of access, various job routines that used this account continued working, as normal, except one.

I'm getting the following error message when the job routine is executed:

```
Executed as user: <MyServerName>\svc_aservice. 
Login failed for user '<Linked server user>'. Reason: The account is disabled. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 18470).
```

However, when executed manually, it works perfectly:

```
The job succeeded.  The Job was invoked by User <MyLogon>.  
The last step to run was step 1 (<StepName>).
```

Solutions I've tryied so far are:

- Creating a new job, inserting the same step: `EXEC [<databaseName>].[<MyProcedure>];`
- Changing the name of the old job

And also, searching up the error message, but it's all related to the logon still being disabled - which is not the case - since it works when executed manually and other jobs continue to run without any errors.

Edit:

1. The SP, executed by the job, is the following:

```sql
DECLARE @STATUS INT
    SET @STATUS = ( 
        SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM [<LinkedServerName>].[database].[dbo].[table] 
        WITH (nolock)
        WHERE <filters>
        )
    IF ( @STATUS > 1 )
    BEGIN
        TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[table]

        INSERT INTO relatorios.dbo.media_du_gerals (
            <values>
            )  
        SELECT <values>
        FROM
        [LinkedServerName].[database].[dbo].[table] 
        WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE <filters>
    END
```

2. The linked server configuration don't have mapped users. Connection is made via **hostname.** I will be checking if connection source via hostname, over IP adress, can be the cause of the problem. If it is the case, I will post an update.

Comment: What user account is listed as the job owner in the SQL Agent job?

Comment: `dbamin` , it's our servers name for the `sa` account. Also, I've verified and it's the same job owner for other jobs that are functioning as normal.

Comment: You really need to include the SP definition (or at least the header) and show how you have your Linked Server configured.  Are you using Delegation or a static user?  Are some users mapped?  More information is needed.

Comment: I've edited the question with more information, as requested. Regarding *delegation or static user*, I'm not familiar with these concepts, and will need to search it up...

Comment: I'm mainly concerned if your SP has an `EXECUTE AS` clause as part of the header.  Basically I want to know of all the places from start-to-finish where impersonation or different user context can occur.   The last thing to check is if the SQL Auth account is orphaned on the other side of the Linked Server via `sp_change_users_login 'report'`

Comment: There is only one job step - my MSSMS is in Portuguese, so maybe my translation is not exact, but the step properties are as following: General - Execute as: `blank` / Advanced - Execute as user: `also in blank`.
Linked Server Safety options: `Will be done using this security context:"`<MyLogon/Password>.

As for checking on the other side of the Linked Server, I will get in touch with the person in charge, to see if there are any results via `sp_change_users_login 'report'`.

If there is any update on that, I will update the question. Thanks in advance!